# Why does JLabel convert any nuber in a string to "..." in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I tried:

```
//All the stuff with JLabel initialization

int Number = 10;
String data = "Value: " + Number;

lbl.setText(data);  //The JLabel says: "Value:..."
System.out.println(data); //The console says: "Value: 10"
```

How can I fix this?
This problem never happened to me before.

Comment: Does your label actually have enough space? What happens if you shorten it to `String data = "X: " + Number;`?

Comment: What layout manager do you use? Can you show the code regarding "_all the stuff with the JLabel initialization_"?

Comment: _**Why does JLabel convert any nuber in a string to “…” in Java?**_ Did you verify this conclusion ? try `System.out.println(lbl.getText());`

Comment: Don't use a null layout and setBounds. Swing was designed to be used with [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). The layout manager will determine the proper size of the label so all the text is displayed.

Comment: Oh I got it, I extended the JLabel and it became normal.

Comment: I really don't know why does java make the text "..."

Comment: this is call an ellipsis, this happens if there are more text than the label can extend. This is a generic a widespread mechanic that exists on web technologies and others languages.